# mining rig 18-0-4 restarting repeatedly

Tags: kernel, startup

i have rx580 aourus amd gigabyte *6
king max ddr4 4gb *3
cpu 4400 intel 
mainboard asus z270 
everything is fine but system is restarting frequently no luck on solve the problem yet